# Trying to get a forecast for 7 day period using Moving average logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to get the moving averages for a window period of 7 days and also forecast the moving averages for the next 7 day period
Like a 7 day forecast using a 7 day moving average.

```
Dates   actual prices Forecast
1 October   5400
2 October   5375
3 October   5350
4 October   5325
5 October   5300
6 October   5275
7 October   5250
8 October   5250
9 October   5200
10 October  5175
11 October  5150
12 October  5125
13 October  5100 
13 October           5325
14 October           5303.571429
15 October           5278.571429
16 October           5253.571429
17 October           5228.571429
18 October           5203.571429
19 October           5178.571429
```

I am not able to forecast using the .rolling(7).mean() function or the .expanding() function.

```
df['7Day_Rolling_avg']=df['actual price'].rolling(window=7).mean()
```

The above code gives me the rolling average but I am not able to forecast the values for the 7 day window period.

[Sample Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmz9V.png)
[Sample Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc1AP.png)

Comment: Please put your code into the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Please could you help me out with a solution to this problem.